# C++ simple and fast single-threaded allocator for small strings working in fixed preallocated memory region?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Looking for single-threaded allocator for small (1...400 bytes) strings, simple enough to be implemented in couple of days, working in preallocated large block of memory (say 1GiB). Must not be noticeably slower than malloc (ptmalloc2) and not too memory-greedy. Key point is: working in preallocated fixed-sized memory region. No multithreading support is needed.

Other related issues about shared memory corruption/conflicts/multithreading and so on are not interesting in this discussion. In my scenario only 1 thread is working with memory. Other scenarios are possible, but considered misuse.

Comment: "Must not be noticeably slower than malloc" Then what is the problem with malloc? malloc is not slower than malloc at all... And what is the scope you use these allocated things? What about alloca? Just a guess, maybe you can use that.

Comment: Consider one of the standard polymorphic allocators?

Comment: If the space is not a problem, then you can use a slab allocator with the maximum size (possibly with a fallback if needed). If the string are all deleted at the same time, a monotonic allocator will be very efficient. If they are in the same function, alloca can be even faster. Otherwise, the basic solution is to use a bucket allocator, but state-of-the-art allocator (eg. jemalloc/glibc) are already extremely optimized. AFAIK, they already use a thread-local buffer and atomic operations efficiently (ie. only if needed) as well as a fast bucket/arena allocator.

Comment: @simre - problem is: malloc does not work in fixed preallocated memory region.

Comment: @pavelkolodin What is the size of the preallocated memory storage what you can use?

Comment: @simre maybe ~2GB